# jquery search list name from table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want do searching follow by [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/rFGWZ/)
but i have `multiple row` to search in `td` value, so how i can add to search with data from all `td` ? 
Thanks!

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/rFGWZ/1069/)

the new jquery :

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

           $row.find("td").each(function(){
               var id =$(this).text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
           });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: my code is can work already for data from the one column to search but what i asked above is i want search with data from multi column result to search

Comment: yes and that code i put there is for searching in multi column test it and you will see

Comment: but your code, i test not work :(

Comment: soo sorry to hear that but can you explain to me what do you want to do exactly i dont quit understand you sorry :(

Comment: by link i give above i can test with search data a column already but i want search with data from more column

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` to find `td` elements within the current row which match the text. Try this:

```
var $row = $(this);
var tdMatches = $('td', $row).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(value) != -1;
}).length;
tdMatches == 0 ? $row.hide() : $row.show()
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rFGWZ/1073/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = this.value.trim();
    if (value) {
        var data = $("table tr td").filter(function () {
            return value == $(this).text();
        }).parent();
        $("table tr:gt(0)").hide();
        data.show();
    } else {
        $("table tr").show();  // all data show if the value is 0 If you want do or remove that
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rFGWZ/1077/)

Comment: @Time check this link http://jsfiddle.net/rFGWZ/1081/

Comment: Your demo is not work,Any my code is can work already for data from the first column to search but what i asked above is i want search with data from multi column result to search